# Sharing styles with document to print

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, microsoft-word-2016

I'm helping someone who is creating a newsletter. Their layout requirements are fairly simple, but will be best served by using some new styles to give a uniform appearance to the text.

The sticking point, where my knowledge reaches its limits, is that it will be sent to a commercial printer. I am assuming that it will go as a Word document, but if that is so, then - even if I have sent a new template to the editor - she will send the basic document to the print shop and they will not interpret the styles correctly and the result will be a dog's breakfast and not the simple, but clear, layout which I have created.

How do I get the document with the instructions from these styles (which will only be used for this project) to the outside printer?

One additional wrinkle is that the document contains pictures which have captions attached. These pictures+captions need to be placed so that the text flows round them on the "square" basis. I have no problem with getting this to look right in the Word document, but any method which will give me the right results in Word 2016 may adversely affect these pictures.

I have looked at the options suggested in

[Automatically remove custom styles from Word document, but save formatting](https://superuser.com/questions/351184/automatically-remove-custom-styles-from-word-document-but-save-formatting)

and some seemingly promising methods e.g. copy and paste into WordPad to strip styles whilst retaining formatting, fall down on this matter of the pictures and their formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Send the document to the Commercial Printer as a PDF not as a Word document format. The PDF will have the necessary formatting.

Comment: Thank you, I had wondered about that. I know there will be "consumer resistance" on that one. Unfortunately, the front cover includes a graphic which the printer is supposed to produce from a submitted file. I suspect that he could not do this trick from a submitted pdf

Comment: @deeplyblue They should be able to do that. We often send a separate PDF for the cover page but include one also in the main document. The reason for this is we want to have the print house to over size the cover so the background/graphic can bleed the edge. They do that by oversizing the single page and then trimming it to size. The cover page can then be printed in color, while rest of the document is in BW.